# Development process, deployment, GitHub

Tags: deployment, github, capistrano, web-deployment

I am trying to bed down a development process for our team.

We have 3/4 disperate developers working on our code base at any one time.

We have started using GIT and the idea is that is piece of work is more than a live fix, then they fork the master branch.

Everyone has their own dev environment on the server, and we have one staging environment which should at all times be a copy of the master branch.

Developers develop on their local, then merge back into the master branch, which should then push their changes to the staging server ([I want to set up something like this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh/)).

If all is approved, then the changes should be copied live. I want to automate this somehow, not sure how exactly. We are using GitHub, so I'm sure there are automated deploy scripts out there.

We only have 1 live server though so it'd be nice if only changed files on the master branch could be deployed to the live server.

Any ideas how to do this?

Is this approach sound?

Any other comments/ warnings?

Is a load balancer necesary to do things like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My company following nearest by [this blog](http://blog.romebuilder.com/2011/07/448/).

We create the **master** branch for production. **My case is for web development**.

Step we do is

Developer fork their feature/bug from **master**

```
git checkout -b feature/featureA
git checkout -b bug/B
```

With this way, we will got the fresh code with already in the released line. In staging server, we use **testing** branch. So, when any feature want to going test, it will merge to that branch

In staging server we use

```
git checkout testing
git pull
```

There are **release** branch handling the hot fix, every hot fix will merge to this branch before merge to master. The idea is that release branch will packing some commits before merge to master which if the problem occurs, it just use command like

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

for temporary.

**Let see my full working Step**

```
git checkout master # Go to Master
git checkout -b feature/New  # New branch
```

Email come from boss to fix critical bug

```
git stash 
git checkout master
git checkout -b hotfix/a
```

do things

```
git commit
git checkout release
git merge hotfix/a
git checkout master
git merge release # In case that you want to pack all ready to production
```

In production

```
git tag -d previous
git tag previous
git pull
```

Oops! not working

```
git checkout previous
```

New commit merged

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Continue my job

```
git checkout feature/New
git stash pop #Restore workspace
git commit
git checkout testing # ready to mix a test
git merge feature/New
```

**Ready to release the feature**

```
git checkout release
git merge feature/New
```

This is because all things in testing branch ready to deploy. So, when merge all ready feature to **release** branch, now, you can make final test.

When everything now go production, we do

```
git checkout testing
git merge master
git checkout release
git merge master
```

**Automate script**

I think you may look into `.git/hooks/post-commit.sample` for hookup some script after you commit the code? anyway, I never use it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have made some adaption based on your post and the blog you linked to.