# Deployment Process for DevOps/Agile

Tags: web-deployment, agile, continuous-deployment

I'm currently trying to implement a deployment process (I think that’s what you call it?)

A former Company I worked for used to have 3 Environments and were using some form of DevOps.

- dev.url => Development for Devs
- stage.url => Staging for QA
- (live.)url

Finished Features would be pulled on stage for QA. When QA gave the go it got a Tag and that tag then was pulled on the live environment. It was all in combination with Agile.

So my Question would be:

**Do you know the name of that Deployment-Process ?**/
**Do you know further popular Deployment-Processes similar to the one I just described ? or What kind of process do you use ?**

I'm looking for something like:
[Development process, deployment, GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230645/development-process-deployment-github)

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like Continuous Integration.

Comment: Same as above with a link : http://jenkins-ci.org/
Jenkins is one of the best opensource continuous integration server

Comment: so jenkins implements this dev->stage->live process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you are looking for is called as [Deployment Pipeline](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DeploymentPipeline.html) which as mentioned by @prasanna is the key part of [Continuous Delivery](http://martinfowler.com/books/continuousDelivery.html).  Key for Continuous Delivery is Continuous Integration [which in turn requires automated tests] and automated deployment with Configuration Management tools.

Regarding the tool, you can use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) along with its [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin).

Comment: That was something I was looking for. Thank you very much! I've just started working with Jenkins and will look into this Plugin once I get comforatble with the tool !

Answer (score 0):

Of-course this is continuos delivery. But the devil is in the details.

- What do you do when things move from Dev->QA->Staging->Prod
- What tests are run when the build is across these stages
- How does the promotion between environments happen (automated/manual) etc.

The key in CD is to ensure that you try to automate all these as deep as possible to you can take faster decisions when builds get stuck in any of these environments.

Comment: I agree, that this process should be automated as far as possible, but I'm still at the beginning. Do you know a system or model I could look up for such an implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned in the above two answers you are referring to Continuos delivery. Now there can be multiple levels of maturity in Continuos delivery. You start with having a Continuos Integration process in place which essentially means that the code is compiled frequently to check for possible failures.

Then you put some checks on the compiled code which get triggered automatically.

Then you go ahead and deploy this code.

The next step to this would be where the environment where the code is deployed is also provisioned on the fly.